# Why current and "old" value of the same expression in a postcondition are equal?

Tags: eiffel

I'm trying to get the value of an entry in a 2D-array before the implementation and afterwards. But the following postcondition is failing because the 2 entries are somehow the same (and yes, I have redefined **is_equal**, so that **~** will be object equality):

```
    ensure
        designated_cell_changed:
            get_entry (row + 1, column + 1) /~ old get_entry (row + 1, column + 1)
```

Why do I get a postcondition violation `designated_cell_changed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several reasons:

1. It's suspicious why the indexes are `row + 1` and `column + 1` instead of `row` and `column`.
2. If the feature in question takes a new value explicitly, e.g. `put (value: G; row, column: ...)`, it should have a precondition

   ```
   require
       different_value: value /~ entry (row, column)
   ```

   *Side note:* for queries it's recommended to use nouns or adjectives, not verbs, thus `entry` instead of `get_entry`.
3. If the feature does not take a new value as an argument, it should update the corresponding value itself.
4. There could be mistakes in the code of the feature:

   - It does not change the value all the time (e.g., in some conditional branches).
   - It changes the value but at some other indices.
5. If the values of `entry (row + 1, column + 1)` at the beginning and at the end of the feature are different, the implementation of `is_equal` may miss some cases that make the objects different.

Comment: Thanks, it violates when the new value to be assigned to the cell is the SAME as the old value.